# READ_SMS and SEND_SMS permission alternative

Tags: android, sms, android-permissions, restriction

In connection with the new permission policy from Google, we recently received a message about a violation of this policy in our application. Our application is an anti-theft, it allows you to get the coordinates of a lost device, as well as perform a photo and audio recording of the thief who stole the device. To receive a request and send a response, the application needs permissions `RECEIVE_SMS` and `SEND_SMS`, without them the main functionality of the application will not work. Sending the Permissions Declaration Form to Google did not bring any results. Are there any alternatives to using the `RECEIVE_SMS` and `SEND_SMS` permissions in our application? Thanks.

Comment: We are running into similar issues. What response did you get for Permissions Declaration Form? Thanks.

Comment: We have not received any response from Permissions Declaration Form.

Comment: I am facing a very similar issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65133829/app-update-rejected-stating-that-i-sush-com-toto-sush-does-not-qualify-for-us Pretty disheartened, was working on my app update since past 4-5 months. And it has been rejected, as my app needs to send SMS to an incoming calling number

Answer (score 1):

Receive-  use any other communication system.  Send a FCM message instead. Or send a binary port based SMS.  But FCM is better.

Sending-  what do you need to send?  I can't see anywhere where sending data by SMS would be more convenient for this kind of app than sending it via network.  You could always send it to your server, then have your server send an SMS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The proposal to use binary sms is very interesting. However, don't you need permission RECEIVE_SMS to get them?
Our application works without a server. Also, its advantage is that some functions (such as determining the coordinates of the device) can work without the Internet, using SMS-request and SMS-response.

Comment: We have verified and found that DATA_SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION also requires RECEIVE_SMS permission. So there is no solution at the moment.

Answer (score -2):

There are no alternative to those security rules and checks. That's how Android works and that's how Android's policies are thought to work.

What you received in that message is something very easy to implement. They require you to just add an explicit permission request, such as you can find in the examples here: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

You just have to add those requests, and your app will be totally compliant with the security policies.

Comment: This isn't what he's talking about.  He's talking about https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/ which is a new Google Play requirement on top of the permission system