# App update rejected, stating that my app Sush, com.toto.sush, does not qualify for use of READ_SMS, SEND_SMS, READ_CALL_LOG

Tags: android, android-permissions, restriction, google-developers-console, android-sms

I've developed an android app ['Sush'](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.toto.sush). It is a utility app which caters to 'Flip-to-vibrate' functionality. I developed the first version back in 2017.

Now i've updated my app to support latest android devices, and also updated the target SDK version.
Along with this, i've also added an new core functionality of 'Quick response SMS'.
With this, one can configure an SMS, which can be sent to the incoming calling number upon flipping the phone face-down.

To implement this feature, my app had to seek following permissions **READ_SMS, SEND_SMS, READ_CALL_LOG** to know the phone number of incoming call, and send a configured SMS accordingly when app is in action.

[link to sush's AndroidManifest.xml file](https://github.com/abhinavganguly1987/flip-sush/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)

When i drafted my release, and proceeded to publish, my app got rejected, stating that my app is not qualified to use above permissions.

I then appealed this decision.
A person named Arthur from Google Play team replied to my appeal with following,

> Thanks for contacting the Google Play team.
>
> I’ve reviewed your appeal request and found that Sush, com.toto.sush,
> does not qualify for use of READ_SMS, SEND_SMS, READ_CALL_LOG for the
> following reasons:
>
> Requested permissions do not match core functionality of the app. You
> declared Default SMS handler, Default Phone handler (and any other
> core functionality usage while default handler) as the core
> functionality of your app. However, after review, we found that your
> app does not match the declared use case(s). You need to ensure that
> your app no longer uses READ_SMS, SEND_SMS, READ_CALL_LOG or make
> changes to your app's metadata to prominently advertise your app as
> Default SMS handler, Default Phone handler (and any other core
> functionality usage while default handler) or Select a use case that
> matches your app’s functionality; failure to do so could result in the
> removal of your app and may impact your developer account.
>
> Permission requests should make sense to users. You may only request
> permissions that are necessary to implement critical current features
> or services in your application. You may not use permissions that give
> access to user or device data for undisclosed, unimplemented, or
> disallowed features or purposes. For additional guidance, please
> review the Permissions policy and this Play Console Help Center
> article.
>
> Please let me know if you have any other questions.
>
> Regards, Arthur
> The Google Play Team

Can someone please help me?
If there is a way in which i can implement this feature without using above permissions?

I assume it is not possible.

If that is so, then why my app is not "qualified" to use these permissions.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Play store no longer accepts apps with SMS permissions unless core functionality of said app is sms messaging. Your chances of being granted an exception are pretty much null so you either have to scrap that functionality and remove permissions or publish somewhere else.

Comment: @Pawel, what if he updated his Permissions declaration form to only reflect Device Automation, which, to my way of thinking, is what he is doing?

Comment: @Bink it doesn't matter, if it's not an SMS app it will be denied for holding SMS permissions. You will not be granted an exception unless there are special circumstances (eg. government-backed app).

Comment: Hi @Pawel thanks for the suggestion. I've tried that, and unfortunately i've received the same sort of "Rejection" email